# Getting QueryString for Model in ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a simple form based on a model.

One of the features I have to support is the ability to create a url of the current paraments of the model. For example:

```
Form Begin
  Model.Name
  Model.Age
Form End
```

Then in javascript some how get:

```
http://Site/Controller/Action?Name=Bill&Age=45
```

Is there a helper that will take the current state and gen a Url?

The reason is that I need to be able to open a new window with the values of the model while leaving the form and page as is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this in your javascript

```
var url = "@Html.Action("Action", "Controller", new { Name = Model.Name, Age = Model.Age})";
window.open(url);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use window.location and then window.open to open it in a new window/page/tab.
For example: 
var myURL = window.location.href; and then use window.open(myURL)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there isn't a way to get what you are asking (nice idea though). I upvoted NKD because of the second part of your question which was on how to open the browser in a new window (perhaps you already knew how to do this).

you would need to use the JQuery/Javascript way of obtaining the values you desire. Alternatively you could make a quick client helper where you give it the key name you are after, it would find it and give it back to you i.e:

```
function GetValueFromForm(key)
{
   return $('#' + key).val();
}
```

then you call it:

```
var url = '/SomeAction?name=' + GetValueFromForm('Name') + '&age=' + GetValueFromForm('Age');
```

Alternatively, if the data is NOT changing then just use the Model values in your javascript:

```
var url = '/SomeAction?name=' + @Model.Name + '&age=' + @Model.Age;
```